# How to Change the dynamic header image for the one template for each page in wordpress? If anyone can help for 4.4 version of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I am creating wordpress theme by scratch so I am facing problem with template , Becouse I am using only one template for  each page for speed improvement .

Comment: How are you setting your header image? Are you doing it via `the_post_thumbnail();` or a custom field? The template should have the global `$post` object available. You should be able to target anything you entered specific to that page with that object, be it the ID or some other data provided.

Comment: @Ty Baily ,  Doing via Custom field not via  the_post_thumbnail(); and I a rendering each page with a template but  I am not able to pick image for header from page section .

Comment: I want same like Featured image enable in function.php if there is any substitute for  the Featured Image where I can select header image from  page section .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each page , you have $post object available.

You than need to use `get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'large');` in the while(or any custom) loop to get the banner.

You also can create custom meta field by [Advanced custom fields plugin](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqrvH2grPTAhWMqY8KHRjpAMwQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwordpress.org%2Fplugins%2Fadvanced-custom-fields%2F&usg=AFQjCNFTanzz4mb4M53jt-vbrKLGvVomlg)

```
get_post_meta($post->ID,'banner',true);
```

Comment: @Ahmad Ginani ->I tried same thing but I don't want to use any plugin for this purpose .

Comment: Can you paste your code in pastebin and send link here?